# CloudWatch to delete old backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently using AWS CloudWatch to create backups of a particular EBS volume every 12 hours and would like to delete old snapshots every so often so I don't end up with a crazy amount of backups. Based on the simpler route I'd like to either replace the existing backup with a new one every time rule triggers OR delete backups older than 2 days. Any idea how to accomplish this?

I tried search Target actions in the CloudWatchAWS console for something like "EC2 DeleteSnapshot API call" or similar with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Lambda function that does this and then invoke that Lambda from a scheduled CloudWatch Event. Beware the maximum execution time of Lamda though. Alternatively you could run an instance and cron a script that does this too. Whichever way you go, you’ll need to script it.